# How to write an xml in WP7 with existing stream

Tags: .net, rss, windows-phone, rss-reader, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to develop an RSS reader application and I want to cache my RSS fedd. What I'm going to do is, to create an XML file in isolated storage using URL loaded feed. Here's what I've done so far.

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isstorage.FileExists(rssCacheFile))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reading from cache");
                readCache(rssCacheFile);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reading from web");
                readFeed(rssLink);
            }
        }
    }

    public void readFeed(string link) 
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(link, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        Stream rssStream = e.Result;
        XmlReader response = XmlReader.Create(rssStream);
        SyndicationFeed feeds = SyndicationFeed.Load(response);

        foreach (SyndicationItem f in feeds.Items) 
        {
            itemList.Add(new RssItem {Title = f.Title.Text });
        }

        listBox1.ItemsSource = itemList;

        //Write to the cache
        writeXML(rssStream);
    }

    public void writeXML(Stream rssStream) 
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isstream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(rssCacheFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, isstorage))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[rssStream.Length];
                while (rssStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                {
                    isstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

                isstream.Flush();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void readCache(string fileName) 
    {
        //IsolatedStorageFile isstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isstorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (isstorage)
                    {
                        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isstorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            rssXml.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cache is empty....");
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that, I can't read from the written XML file. When I check for the existence of the file, it's there. But I can't read from it. Can anyone tell me a solution for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Updated : I've updated the above code and I don't get any errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't read from it"? If you mean that an exception was thrown, you should fix your catch block so that you keep the exception - currently you're discarding all the useful information.

Comment: Jon Skeet, I mean that with the readCache() method, I can't get anything read from the saved xml file to the 'rssXML'(TextBlock).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your isstorage variable in a using because it will dispose it at the end of the using and that's not what you want with a class variable. Also put your stream variable in readCache inside a using so that it'll close and dispose the stream.

Also make sure you check out what the exception is that you get so that we can offer better help.

Comment: MrSoundless Thanks for the answer and I did as you said. Still the problem exists. I don't get any errors and the written file also exist.